# New to Python 3 - Unable to get program to move to the next module

Tags: python, module

I am new to Python and am trying to get a program to move from one defined module to the next. The first module is working just fine but will not move to the def calcAverage module. I have attached both the code and the result. I only have the sum set up in the first module to verify that it was calculating correctly. This info will be returned and printed into a table. (Sorry if I am not using the correct terminology.) I'm very new to this.

Here is the result:
Enter the first test score.89
Enter the second test score.94
Enter the third test score.100
Enter the fourth test score.88
Enter the fifth test score.96
467

> > >
> >     Nothing happens after this.

Here is the code:

`    # This program will calculate the average of five test scores.

```
# Print my name
print('Beth Salvatore')

# Assign corresponding letter grade.
A_score = 90
B_score = 80
C_score = 70
D_score = 60

def main():
    # Get five test scores. Get first score.
    test1 = int(input('Enter the first test score.'))
    # Get second score.
    test2 = int(input('Enter the second test score.'))
    # Get third score.
    test3 = int(input('Enter the third test score.'))
    # Get fourth score.
    test4 = int(input('Enter the fourth test score.'))
    # Get fifth score.
    test5 = int(input('Enter the fifth test score.'))
    # Add all scores.
    x = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]
    total = sum(x)
    print (total)

    # Return the total of all tests.
    return total

def calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5):
    # Find the average of all tests.
    calcAverage = (total) /5.0
    return calcAverage
    print('The average test score is %', calcAverage) 

def determineGrade(score):
    # Assign a letter grade to the average.
    if score >= A_score:
        print('A')
    else:
        if score >= B_score:
            print('B')                           
        else:
            if score >= C_score:
                print ('C')
            else:
                if score >= D_score:
                    print('D')
                else:
                    print('F')

    # Return the letter grade
    return score

    #Print the tests and corresponding grades in a table.
    print('score \t\t numeric grade \t letter grade')
    print('---------------------') \
    print('score 1:' test1, score)
    print('score 2:' test2, score)
    print('score 3:' test3, score)
    print('score 4:' test4, score)
    print('score 5:' test1, score)

# Call the main function.
main()`
```

Comment: You never called the other functions in general.

Comment: You have to actually call `calcAverage()`, just like you called `main()`. Functions aren't automatically executed (in Python or any other language).

Comment: A solution for your to look at and learn from  https://gist.github.com/brunsgaard/4a356691702f7aa31484031ede15a840

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I appreciate your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

def must be declared before the call of *main()*.
You're OK.

But you never called *calcAverage()* nor *determineGrade()* into the def of your **main**.

If your *return(total)* into your **main**, then use *print(main())* (with no sense at all).

Or, if you *print(total*) in your **main**, use *total=test1+test2+...+test5* before.

That's all at this point.

> total = test1+test2+test3+test4+test5
>
> print (total)

```
# Return the total of all tests.
# return total
# because you rarely return a int via a main, until you call the main from elsewhere
```

Just add *determineGrade(total)* into your main after *print(total)*

Comment: You want to see the result of other functions, so you need to call them into your main !